# Return Empty Dataframe using cursor.fetchall()

Tags: python

I have a SQL Query which may return **Empty** or **Non Empty** records. I need to execute this query in Python:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                            user='root',
                            password='root',
                            db='device_db',
                            cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

cur3=connection.cursor()

cur3.execute('SELECT outgoing_db.Customer_No, sum(SUM_IC_CALLS) AS SumOfSUM_IC_CALLS, sum(SUM_AIC_DURATION_C1) AS SumOfSUM_AIC_DURATION_C1, sum(SUM_AIC_AMOUNT_C1) AS SumOfSUM_AIC_AMOUNT_C1, outgoing_db.Rate, outgoing_db.Customer_Name FROM outgoing_db WHERE (((outgoing_db.User_ID) != ("IND")) AND ((outgoing_db.Incoming_ID)="Airtel") AND ((outgoing_db.Customer_Type)="Check") AND ((outgoing_db.Current_Operation)="NO") AND ((outgoing_db.Active)="NO")) GROUP BY outgoing_db.Customer_No, outgoing_db.Rate, outgoing_db.Customer_Name HAVING (((outgoing_db.Customer_No) In (33165,33197)));')
mydf3=pd.DataFrame(cur3.fetchall())
print(mydf3)
```

It is giving me an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\wamp64\www\DevicePortal\Query.py", line 16, in <module>
    mydf3=pd.DataFrame(cur3.fetchall())
  File "C:\Users\Sonal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 404, in __init__
raise ValueError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

When I am doing **cur3.fetchone()** It is giving me an output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

But the data may be added in future (around 1 Million).
Is there a solution to return empty dataframe using **cur3.fetchall()**

Comment: What happens if you use [`pandas.read_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetchall()` returns a list of tuples; if you want to construct a dataframe from them, you can use `pandas.DataFrame.from_records()`

An easier way would be to read the data directly from SQL with:

```
pandas.read_sql()
```

It has a `chunksize` parameter that allows you to load the data chunk-wise if your dataset will be too large.

Read about it here:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html